# How to start a timer when there's input?

Tags: c#, timer, unity-game-engine

In my game I want to have a timer start when a user left clicks. Here is the code I have so far:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Countdown : MonoBehaviour
{
    float timeLeft = 30.0f;
    public Text text;
    public Text scoretext;
    public Text finalscore;
    public AudioSource ping;
    public GameObject ball;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        finalscore.text = "";        
    }

    void countdownfunction()
    {
        timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
        text.text = "Time Left: " + Mathf.Round(timeLeft) + " seconds";
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        countdownfunction();

        if (timeLeft < 0)
        {
            ping = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            text.text = "Time's up!";
            ping.Play();
            ball.SetActive(false);
            finalscore.text = "Final score ^";            
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, a timer starts as soon as the game starts, but I'd like to have it start when a user left-clicks, please let me know if there's a way to do this, thanks.

Comment: Off-topic, but it's somewhat inefficient to call `GetComponent<AudioSource>()` each frame.  Why don't you store it somewhere?

Comment: @MickyD good idea, I'm very new to Unity and C# as I started yesterday. Thanks for the tip though

Comment: No worries, was just a friendly tip :)  Have fun fellow Unity user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Update Function, use the Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) function to check if user left clicked.
Your code will look like:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Countdown : MonoBehaviour
{
    float timeLeft = 30.0f;
    public Text text;
    public Text scoretext;
    public Text finalscore;
    public AudioSource ping;
    public GameObject ball;
    bool timerStarted = false;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        finalscore.text = "";        
    }

    void countdownfunction()
    {
        timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
        text.text = "Time Left: " + Mathf.Round(timeLeft) + " seconds";
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            timerStarted = true;
        if(timerStarted)
            countdownfunction();

        if (timeLeft < 0)
        {
            ping = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            text.text = "Time's up!";
            ping.Play();
            ball.SetActive(false);
            finalscore.text = "Final score ^";            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

It's good to separate your timer from the Update function. Make into another function. Coroutine is perfect for this kind of stuff because you can easily use it to wait for some time then resume operation. Also, cache components if you are going to use them more than once. You will will be using the `ping` variable a lot so it makes sense to cache is in the `Awake` or `Start` function.

```
void Start()
{
    finalscore.text = "";
    ping = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

void Update()
{
    //Check if left mouse button is clicked
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        StartCoroutine(startTimer(30));
    }
}

IEnumerator startTimer(float timeLeft)
{
    while (timeLeft > 0)
    {
        timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
        text.text = "Time Left: " + Mathf.Round(timeLeft) + " seconds";
        yield return null;
    }

    text.text = "Time's up!";
    ping.Play();
    ball.SetActive(false);
    finalscore.text = "Final score ^";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `onMouseDown` event

Add the following to your existing code:
Create a boolean variable, set it to false, make it true onMouseDown and start timer only if it's set to true:

```
private bool mouseClicked=false;

void OnMouseDown(){
 mouseClicked = true;
}

void Update () {

    if (mouseClicked){
        countdownfunction();
    }

    if (timeLeft < 0)
    {
        ping = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        text.text = "Time's up!";
        ping.Play();
        ball.SetActive(false);
        finalscore.text = "Final score ^";


    }
}
```